# Calculator software to solve simple equations

Tags: windows, gratis, math, calculator

I need a Windows calculator software that is able to solve simple equations like ohm's law:

```
U = R.I
```

Where I can input *R* and *I* values and it pops out the *U* value.
Of course, this simple equation is just an example. I will be using it with equations more complex with more than 5 variables.

It's important that the software is free, and if possible portable too.

Comment: Do you need to solve the equations before inputting? i.e. Is it likely that you enter `R` and `U`, and need the software to solve the equation with respect to `I`?  Which operative system do you want this to run on? Could you give an example of an equation with some more variables, and how you want it handled?

Comment: Will be used on Windows. I want to define the entire equation, provide some variable values, and solve it for a given variable. Another example: br=(uclkdiv/1+(mul/div))/16*val, then I will input some variables leaving the only interested one to be solved by the software.

Answer (score 1):

Well in principle, if I get your question right, you could use any programming language for your application. You would create a script where you define some variables with values at the beginning, and then perform the calculations you want to so.

Might be a bit of overkill, but you can have look at [Python(x,y)](http://python-xy.github.io/). It's a collection of Python modules that can be installed easily, and comes with a nice user interface for the Python programming language, which might helps you getting started more easily. Plus, the Python programming language is very useful in many areas, so I think it's never a failure to have a look at it, anyways :-)

Good luck!

edit: I don't know if there is a portable version by the way, but at least Python can be run on many many platforms!